# Display all text documents in folder in HTML div?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a folder of reviews in the form of `.txt` documents.

I want to be able to load these into a "review showcase" panel on the site. So it would show off what reviews we already have.

I've figured out with PHP how to get the form to save the information in the fields as a `.txt` file, but now I'm wondering how do I put all the `.txt` files into the div?

I have the div configured to scroll, so if I have lets say five reviews, the person browsing can scroll through to read all five of them.

Everything I've seen so far only seems to say "how to put ONE file in the div" like `helloworld.txt` but all of my .`txt` documents have different names.

Comment: Can we see what you have tried so far.

Comment: If you know how to do it once, what is stopping you from doing it four more times?

Comment: @Lamelemon Because the file names cannot be static. I cannot embed them into the HTML. It must be dynamic because they are named by the date they were made. Unless, do you think if I made it so the file names were more like numbers... say "r1.txt, r2.txt, r3.txt" instead of "Oct18.txt" or what have you... You think that might work better if I used some kind of FOR loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load all of the `*.txt` files in a directory you may be interested in [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) something like this would work.

```
$contents = '';
foreach(glob('/path/to/files/*.txt') as $txtFile) {
    $contents .= file_get_contents( $txtFile );
}
echo $contents;
```

The way this works is that the `glob()` function looks for txt files in the directory specified.  This returns an array of filenames.

The `foreach()` construct then iterates through that array.  On each iteration the `$txtFile` variable gets set to be equal to the next value in the file list.

`file_get_contents()` then reads the txt file into a string which is appended to `$content` note the `.=` operator.

Note, that doesn't do any formatting, you may want to wrap each review in its own block element or something like that.

Comment: This is PHP right? I'm not very proficient with the language, forgive me. Is there a way to control

Comment: Apparently enter is not "line break", it is "submit"... Is there a way to control where the "echo" goes? Like if I want the output in a specific div. If this gets all "txt" files in a directory then it's exactly what I need.

Comment: Yes, this is PHP.  You can place that code snippet wherever you want, even inline in your html file. Just wrap it in `<?php  ?>` tags.

Comment: Isn't $txtFile a variable? Is its value already natively defined by the code or do I need to specify it myself?

Comment: It is created by the foreach statement.  I'll add some more detailed explanation on how this works...

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize the "as" was similar in function to an equals sign. Each item in the directory with a txt extension takes on the value of $txtFile, if I'm reading it right then.

Comment: $txtFile takes on the value of each filename that matches *.txt.  Then `file_get_contents()` returns what is actually in the file.

Comment: After futzing with the file navigation for a bit, I managed to get the code to work just as I expected! Thank you.